# How to access a layout from a non-parent activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an activity called Main that its root XML layout is a relative layout. How can I use Fragment to access this relative layout from a different Activity (Let's say "BG" for example)? Here is the Main Activity(it has the relative layout):

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout main; // Its id is "main_layout"

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }   
}
```

And Here's the second activity from which I want to access Main relative layout:

```
public class BG extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout main;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bg);

        setBackground();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void setBackground()
    {
        main = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);???
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/bg.jpg");
        BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
        main.setBackgroundDrawable(bd);
    }
}
```

Can I use this method if I set the Main parent activity to BG in manifest file?

Comment: I am just curious, why do you not want to just set the background in Main?

Comment: I agree with @crazy_Browes ..the mistake is this situation ..you should not want to set from another activity ...maybe you can set some data for example a boolean , and when you will come again in your main you will do things interpreting the data ..

Comment: You know these are sample classes. I want to write an activity like "BG" above to set the background of every item of my app in the start of the application and when I go back and forth between activities it wouldn't have to set the background of an activity again and agian...

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to reach a relative layout from a different activities fragment, or from a fragment to parent activity? If the second one is the case, you can just use getActivity.findViewById(...) and set the background. If first one is the case, well.. you can create an object of the whole class and set the background image of the relative layout of the object which is very..VERY bad.

Comment: Ok, forget about the fragment. Just see my second comment for @Emmanuel answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use Fragment to access this relative layout from a different
>   Activity (Let's say "BG" for example)?

Why would you want to do that?

`Fragments` were designed to be used and managed by `Activities`. One `Activity` can have multiple `Fragments`. If you want your UI to be composed of two "root" layouts you should have two `Fragments` with their respective UI. You can then use the `Activity` to get a reference of each of the `Fragments` and their respective layouts.

If what you want is for all of your `Activities` to share some common functionality, you can create a `BaseActivity` and have all your other `Activities` `extends` from it.

If what you want is a common backround or for that matter, some common attribute that can be defined in xml you should use a [`Theme`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) like WarrenFaith suggested below.

Comment: Ok, is there any different possible way to get access to xml layout from another activity?

Comment: You will have to pass an instance of your current `Activity` to the next `Activity`; this will cause problems. Think about this. What would happen if you try modify the first `Activity` from the second `Activity` after `onDestroy()` was called on the first `Activity`?

Comment: Ok, lets say I have 10 activities that I want to access each one's items from a different single activity. Is it correct that all 10 above extend from the single one? This way they have access to this single activity items. right?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by " I want to access each one's items from a different single activity"...

Comment: Let's say I want to apply a theme for an app when application runs. I have 10 activities with all of their layout items like text-views, image-views etc. The single activity runs at the start of the application and set the background and colors and stuff like that to these 10 activities items. I want to access these items at the start of the application not when I get to each one.

Comment: @AliAllahyar when you want a theme: use a theme! Check [styles and themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) where you can define (nearly) everything in XML and you don't need to have a parent activity with that.

Comment: @WarrenFaith That's interesting. I'd got little info of that. You know I want to get my every style of the app from an external file or collection of files on the sd-card, but these styles written in XML can't satisfy my needs.

Comment: @AliAllahyar I may be misunderstanding you but shouldn't you put the files in the drawable folders? Instead of getting them from the SD card? Then you can call them in the styles.xml and define everything.

Comment: Theme and styles will be the same. You would still need to set your backgrounds within those 10 activities. If your problem is not to declare a bg image to all those activities, pass the image parcelable image with a bundle to the activity and set bg in activity from the bundle. It is the same with using a theme.

Comment: @RED_I know but I have different themes that can be installed from a server and there is no way to put each theme files in the drawable folder at run-time. I want to give user ability to change themes dynamically during the application run-time.

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu That's the same way I've declared and set my images and backgrounds with a single activity at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You just want the same background in your entire app? That's what I understand from the question. If so you need to look in your styles.xml file and set the background or other theme properties there. This will then apply to the rest of you application. So you won't have to set the background for each layout.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html